# SQL Must declare the scalar variable "@UnitList"

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

```
/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetUnitCost] 
     (@CompanyId INT, 
      @UnitList idlist READONLY)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @tep_table TABLE (Name VARCHAR(MAX))

    INSERT INTO @tep_table
        EXEC GetUnitRoot @UnitList

    DECLARE @retVal INT

    SELECT @retVal = COUNT(*) 
    FROM @tep_table

    IF (@retVal = 1)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @MyList TABLE (Value int)
        INSERT INTO @MyList
        select @UnitList.Id from @UnitList

        DECLARE @Secondx TABLE (Id int, [WorkHours] [float], SalesPriceTotal int, cvr varchar(MAX))
        while exists (select * from @MyList)
        begin
                declare @TableID int = (select top 1 [Value] from @MyList)
                INSERT INTO @Secondx
                SELECT
                    [dbo].[Unit].Id
                    ,WorkHours
                    ,SalesPriceTotal
                    ,[dbo].[Company].Cvr
                FROM [dbo].[Unit] 
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[Company] ON [dbo].[Unit].CompanyId  = [dbo].[Company].Id
                where [dbo].[Unit].Id = @TableID and [dbo].[Unit].CompanyId = 4
            DELETE TOP (1) FROM @MyList
        end
    select Id, Sum(WorkHours) as WorkHours, SUM(SalesPriceTotal) as SalesPriceTotal, cvr from @Secondx group by Id, cvr
    End
End
```

How do I solve the issue with

> Must declare the scalar variable "@UnitList"

I need to get following result:

```
Id   WorkHours       SalesPriceTotal     Cvr
------------------------------------------------
716   2,5            3000                123456
764   3              1000                123456
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet you need to alias that tvp.

```
select UL.Id from @UnitList UL
```

Comment: Yup perfect, i will approve in 10 min when i can